# Haskell Test Practice Stuck on Tables and Mapping Functions

Tags: haskell, dictionary, filter, mapping

This is the question from my exam practice paper:

```
The following table gives the names, grades and age of people employed by a 
company: 

Name       Grade     Age 
Able       Director  47 
Baker      Manager   38 
Charles    Trainee   19 
Dunn       Director  50 
Egglestone Manager   42 

i. Define a Haskell type suitable for representing the information in such a 
table [10%] 

A function avAge is required to find the average age of people in a given grade, 
for instance in the example the average age of managers is 40. Give three 
alternative Haskell definitions for this function: 

ii. using explicit recursion, [20%] 
iii. using mapping functions, [20%] 
iv. using list comprehensions. [20%]
```

The table isn't very clear as I couldn't paste the proper table but you can basically see there are 3 columns and multiple rows, one for name, one for grade, one for age. So as you can see the first question "i" is to define a haskell type that is suitable for representing an information in such a table. Keep in my that the real table has lines of course.

So how do I define a function to do this? Does define a function mean e.g. "[String] -> String -> Int" or I have to write up a function that does something?

Finally, about the avAGe to find the average age of people what are the ideas behind doing it with mapping functions? I have planned out for explicit recursion but I'm really struggling to fit mapping functions (map, foldr, filter, etc) to this.

Comment: You can make a function `age :: Employee -> Int` (either using record structure for your data type or defining it using pattern matching). Then `map age :: [Employee] -> [Int]`, but you'll want to convert those to Double or Float using map as well (search hoogle for a function that converts Int to Double or Float). You can define both `sum` and `count` using foldr, but if you like, you could do count by mapping `const 1` and then summing.

Comment: @AndrewC, the employee is irrelevant here. All that's needed is a function from `Grade` to `Double`. Most of the table is completely irrelevant. That's what makes this question absurd.

Comment: @dfeuer No, I use the employees because you can first filter for the grade you're seeking the average age of.

Comment: @AndrewC, my point is that data structures should generally be chosen based on how they're going to be used. In this case, given no further information, an appropriate data structure would be a function from `Grade` to the average age of the employees with that grade. Neither the employees' names nor their ages must be stored. If we also want to be able to look things up by employee name, grade, or age, or calculate other statistics, etc., then a richer data structure would start to make sense.

Comment: @dfeuer But the question first asks _i. Define a Haskell type suitable for representing the information in such a table_. I would choose a list-based type for that, not a function, and I interpret parts ii, iii and iv as asking for functions taking this data type as an argument. I would expect to be penalised if I chose a type which either excluded or summarised some of the data in the table, as it would't represent all the data in the table. If you choose a function from Grade to Double, you can only answer parts ii, iii and iv with three bizzarely convoluted definitions of id.

Comment: @AndrewC, for many (in fact, probably most) purposes, a list would be a poor choice for this sort of information. A multimap with names as keys seems more natural, but again it would depend on what kinds of things you need to do.

Comment: @dfeuer But you would still lose marks in the subsequent parts which clearly expect you to use lists. The things you need to do are find the average age of each grade using ii explicit recursion (hard for a map, easy for a list), iii mapping functions (easy for both) and iv list comprehensions (easiest for a list). You seem to have trouble accepting this test question on its own terms.

Answer (score 6):

A suitable type would be one where each row has a data type and maybe you can use an existing collection type for holding multiple rows.  To start you off:

```
data Entry = Entry __________ deriving (Eq, Show)
type Entries = __________
```

So what should go in the blank?  It'll need to be able to hold a name, a grade, and an age.  For `Entries`, you should be able to use a built-in type to store all these rows, presumably in order.

Are the grades from a fixed number of valid values?  Then you might consider using an ADT to represent them:

```
data Grade
    = Trainee
    | Manager
    | Director
 -- | AnyOtherNameYouNeed
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

If not, then you can just use `String`s, but I would still give them a name:

```
type Grade = String
```

So now that you have your types set up, you can work on the implementations of `avAge`.  You need explicit recursion, mapping, and list comprehension.  The function needs to take `Entries` and a `Grade` and return an average of the ages that match that `Grade`, so the type signature should probably be

```
avAgeRec :: Entries -> Grade -> Double
avAgeRec entries grade = __________

avAgeMap :: Entries -> Grade -> Double
avAgeMap entries grade = __________

avAgeComp :: Entries -> Grade -> Double
avAgeComp entries grade = __________
```

This should help you get started, I just don't want to give you the answers since this is a study problem, and it's always better to come up with the answers yourself =)

---

So now you have

```
type Grade = String
type Entry = (String, Grade, Int)
type Entries = [Entry]
```

And with a little filled in from the comments below:

```
avAgeRec :: Entries -> Grade -> Double
avAgeRec entries grade = __________

avAgeMap :: Entries -> Grade -> Double
avAgeMap entries grade = <calculate average> $ map <get ages> $ filter <by grade> entries

avAgeComp :: Entries -> Grade -> Double
avAgeComp entries grade = __________
```

Can you get a few more of the blanks filled in now?

Comment: Thank you this has helped but please put in as much to the answer as you can and I'll post my code for a check after, I need to find a way to do this as the exam is tomorrow! I figure things out easier doing it from the back forward - seeing how its done then figuring out how it all works. I need to be effecient with my time now so any more help is appreciated!

Comment: @darkphoton post some of what you have now and I'll add more to my answer. I'd like to see your effort first.

Comment: @darkphoton How about this, can you fill in the first two blanks of my answer?  What should come after `data Entry = Entry` and `type Entries = `?

Comment: ok give me a bit of time I just finished the final part for my preparation, now just this type of question left so I'll be working on this solely. I'll get back to you soonish

Comment: so far only:
`type Entries = [(String,Int)] -- storing name and age in a tuple
            data Entry = Name | Grade | Age`
Can't figure out how to make a type for 3 columns with the "Grade" as well, so far I can only think of tuple to store name and age of the person, and have a data type of Name Grade or Age.

Comment: @darkphoton what about storing the grade?

Comment: I just edited to say I'm not sure, because from what I was taught in this first month of programming tuples only have 2 parts to it? How can I store 3 things into one list without using tuples?

Comment: @darkphoton you could use a custom data type, such as a record type, or you could simply use a 3 tuple. Tuples can have more than 2 elements, it's just that they have fixed size at compile time.

Comment: so for defining a type for the table part (i), 
`type = [(String. String. Int)]` would work?

Comment: @darkphoton Yes, it would work, but you'd need commas instead of periods, and you also have to give it a name.  So `type Entry = [(String, String, Int)]`.  Now, I would recommend trying to implement the `map` and `filter` version first, as I personally would consider it the easiest.  The steps you'll need to perform are 1) filter the list to get only the specified grade; 2) map a function on the result from step 1 to get all the ages; 3) calculate the average of those ages.